# Manifest merger failed with multiple errors,see logs

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-manifest

sorry to disturb but I have tried many answers on internet but every is solving sdk problem my AndroidManifest.xml don't show any problem and yet my code is not running.please help me and sorry for that much silly question. I am adding image for better understanding

Comment: Please edit your question and add your Manifest file code with error log

Answer (score -1):

try if this can help: downgrade the targetSdkVersion in app/build.gradle to 30.
Hope this help. Have a nice day.